# Is it possible to add text(placeholder or label) to input type="color" and leave it clickable?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have `<input type='color' value="#eeeeee">`. And input shows only chosen colour (background-color). Is there's a way to place text (placeholder/value) over this background or may be remove background-color?
I tried a label with absolute position. But it covers the colour-picker.

[image]

Comment: Use a styled drop down list instead?

Comment: `input type=color` does not support placeholders https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/input.color.html. Your question is currently a bit broad, what is the final result you are after and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to use a label with absolute position, but not much convenient. I try to find out easier way (if exist). The result I want I put on my topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with some js and a label

```js
function changeLabel(){
  const color = document.querySelector('#test').value;
  document.querySelector('label[for="test"]').innerHTML = color.toString();
}

window.onload = () => {
  document.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('change', changeLabel);
  changeLabel();
}
```

```html
<input id="test" type="color" value="#eeeeee" >
<label for="test">init</label>
```

And If you want you can hide the input with css(`#test{display:hidden;}`)

If you want to keep the color, just apply it to the background of the label.

Comment: Yeah. I tried label with absolute position, but could solve the problem with background. Thank you.

Comment: Just be aware that for darker colors you should use a white color for your text

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about it is style the input with `position: absolute;` and placing it underneath the label with `z-index: -1;`.

The label have to have 'for' attribute with the same value as the input id (to trigger the input action)

I made a quick example in [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wkvo0qnw25)